# What's the difference between INNER and LEFT join in DELETE statement?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, foreign-key-relationship, sql-delete

When doing a delete I can zap rows in two or more tables by doing a `LEFT JOIN`.

```
DELETE a, b FROM
table1 a
LEFT JOIN table2 b on (a.id = b.id)
WHERE ...
```

I can also do an `INNER JOIN`

```
DELETE a, b FROM
table1 a
INNER JOIN table2 b on (a.id = b.id)
WHERE ...
```

What **exactly** is the difference between these two?

**And what about other joins**
Does it make sense to use other join types in a `delete` statement and how would these be useful?

**What's the difference between a delete ... join and using a foreign key**
If I set a foreign key with a `ON DELETE CASCADE` clause:

1. Does that match an `INNER` or 'LEFT' join (or none of the above)?
2. Is that somehow 'better' (faster/more secure) than using a join?

I'm using MySQL, but I'd also like to know which other databases support it.

Comment: It's not "universal". Not all DBMS allow a JOIN with a DELETE statement. So it should rightfully be tagged with mysql

Comment: @thirsty_horse, PostgreSQL, SQL-server, DB2, Oracle do.

Comment: SQL Server doesn't allow this multi table `DELETE` though. Only 1 table can be the target of the `DELETE` operation. `DELETE a, b ...` would be invalid.

Comment: @Martin, thanks learned a new thing today...

Comment: @le dorfier, OK, surprised at that. You happen to know which databases support it?

Comment: I know sql server, sybase, oracle, and postgresql don't. I've never used it except in mysql

Comment: @Johan: Oracle does not allow a JOIN in a DELETE statement. PostgreSQL does support JOINs for DELETE but not a multi-table delete

Comment: I just checked DB2 - it doesn't either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is that the inner join won't delete anything that doesn't join.  The left join can delete things that don't join depending on what is in your `WHERE` clause.

Comment: So **only** the inner join will preserve referential integrity?

Comment: @Johan: No. Referential integrity depends on declared integrity constraints and on constraints implemented in rules and triggers. Unless there's a bug, no database update (as in INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE) can change rows in ways that violate integrity constraints. But the result of complex statements--such as DELETE statements that include outer joins--have been known to surprise even seasoned DBAs. And many, many database "designers" implement integrity constraints with hope and wishful thinking. Neither of those scale well.